# Связь один к одному

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

Model. В таблицах указал

```
CONSTRAINT [FK_Profiles_Infos] FOREIGN KEY ([InfoId])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[Infos] ([Id]) ON DELETE SET NULL
CONSTRAINT [FK_Сars_Infos] FOREIGN KEY ([InfoId])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[Infos] ([Id]) ON DELETE SET NULL
```

```
namespace Meditid.Models
{
    public class Info
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual Profile Profile { get; set; }
        public virtual Collection<Car> Car { get; set; }
    }
    public class Profile
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string MiddleName { get; set; }
        public int InfoId { get; set; }
        public virtual Info info { get; set; }
    }
    public class Car
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string CarName { get; set; }
        public string CarNumber { get; set; }
        public int InfoId { get; set; }
        public virtual Info info { get; set; }
    }
    public class SContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Profile> Profiles { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Car> Cars { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Info> Infos { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Функция формирования json'a из 3 таблиц

```
public string Lowx()
{
    var query = db.Infos
        .Include(x => x.Profile)
        .Include(x => x.Car)
        .ToList();
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(query.ToList());
}
```

Выдает исключение:

> System.InvalidOperationException: "Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the types 'Meditid.Models.Profile' and 'Meditid.Models.Info'. The principal end of this association must be explicitly configured using either the relationship fluent API or data annotations."

[image: Intelisence не показывает ни HasOne, ни with..., ни WithOne/WithRequired,WithMany]

Comment: Вам ваши связи необходимо указать в DbContext. Например, через FluentAPI. Ну или аннотации использовать в описании самих классов

Comment: @MrModest можете привест пример аннотаций в классах?

Comment: @MrModest ваши правки интересны. 1 вариант не сработал, ошибка осталась. во 2 варианте сначала ругалось на ModelBuilder и на все вокруг, я поменял на DbModelBuilder. Теперь ругается на HasOne и WithOne/WithMany я поменял на HasKey, но не могу найти аналога к with

Comment: `HasKey` это другое. это устанавливает `PrimaryKey`. Попробуйте `WithRequered` или `WithOptional` в зависимости от того, что вам нужно.. Аналогично и с `Has`

Comment: @MrModest вообще нет синтаксиса с with

Comment: это странно.. покажите ваш DbContext после измненений

Comment: @MrModest скрин в конце моего описания проблемы

Comment: пробовали меня на `HasRequired` и `WithRequired`?

Comment: вот тут ещё можете сами глянуть: https://metanit.com/sharp/entityframework/6.2.php

Comment: @MrModest я читал статью. Я пробовал менять, hasone на hasrequired но with вообще нет.

Comment: какая версия EF у вас?

Comment: @MrModest 6.2 версия

Comment: тогда странно, ибо в той статье именно он и описывается. Я лично работал только с EF Core (или EF 7 его ещё называют)

Answer (score 1):

Используйте `DataAnnotation` ([Подробнее](https://metanit.com/sharp/entityframework/6.3.php)):

```
namespace Meditid.Models
{
    public class Info
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public virtual Profile Profile { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Car> Car { get; set; }
    }
    public class Profile
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string MiddleName { get; set; }

        public int InfoId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("InfoId")]
        public virtual Info Info { get; set; }
    }
    public class Car
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string CarName { get; set; }
        public string CarNumber { get; set; }
        public int InfoId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Info")]
        public virtual Info info { get; set; }
    }
}
```

или же можно использовать `FluentAPI` ([Подробнее](https://metanit.com/sharp/entityframework/6.2.php)):

```
public class SContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Info> Infos { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Profile> Profiles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Car> Cars { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        builder.Entity<Info>()
            .HasOne(i => i.Profile)
            .WithOne(p => p.Info)
            .HasForeignKey<Profile>(p => p.InfoId);

        builder.Entity<Info>()
            .HasMany(i => i.Cars)
            .WithOne(c => c.Info)
            .HasForeignKey<Car>(c => c.InfoId);
    }
}
```